# Add custom css to html code with jsoup

Tags: java, jquery, android, css, jsoup

I'm working on an Android app, which loads a HTML page and shows it in a webview.
The problem is I want to add my custom css (the loaded HTML hasn't any CSS or link to a css). How do I add the custom css to the HTML code using jsoup?
I cant modify the html.
And how does the webview can open it afterwards?
Thank you

Comment: It's not an identical question. I can't load it with loadDataWithBaseURL because there isn't any link to a ccs in the HTML. So i can't refer to a css in the local App.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Several ways. You can use [`Element#append()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) to append some piece of HTML to the element.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element head = document.head();
head.append("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://example.com/your.css\">");
```

Or, use [`Element#attr(name, value)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#attr%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to add attributes to existing elements. Here's an example which adds `style="color:pink;"` to all links.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements links = document.select("a");
links.attr("style", "color:pink;");
```

Either way, after modification get the final HTML string by [`Document#html()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#html%28%29).

```
String html = document.html();
```

Write it to file by [`PrintWriter#write()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PrintWriter.html#write%28java.lang.String%29) (with the right charset).

```
String charset = Jsoup.connect(url).response().charset();
// ...
Writer writer = new PrintWriter("/file.html", charset);
writer.write(html);
writer.close();
```

Finally open it in the webview. Since I can't tell it from top of head, here's just a link with an example which I think is helpful: [WebViewDemo.java](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/src/com/google/android/webviewdemo/WebViewDemo.java). I found the link on [this blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-webviews.html) by the way (which I in turn found by Google).

Comment: Whats is the right charset? What I have to put in there "//..." ?

Comment: The right charset is the `Jsoup.connect(url).response().charset();`. The `//...` is just the code you need to get the `html`.

Comment: Thank you but when I put this to eclipse it says: "Add throws decleration"
...
public void main(String... args) throws 
 FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
try{
...
What I have to do?

Comment: Just add `throws IOException` to the method signature or put it in try-catch. Did you explore the suggestions which Eclipse gave when you click the red bullet?

Comment: Okay I've put a try-catch.
But now It says in the webview: The Web page at file:///android_asset/file.html could not be loaded as: The request file was not found. file.html

Comment: You keep posting unrelated questions as comments. Your initial question of adding custom CSS is been answered. I'd suggest to press `Ask Question` button for new questions.

Comment: This is my code after the writer:

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      main();
      
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest way is to search and replace on the HTML text to insert your custom styles, before loading it into your `WebView`. I do this in my app BBC News to restyle the news article page slightly. My code looks like this:

```
text = text.replace("</head>",
        "<style>h1 {font-size: x-large;} h1, div.date, div.storybody, img {margin:4px; padding:4px; line-height:1.25;}</style></head>");
```

See how I search and replace on the end `head` tag (including my own `</head>` tag in the replaced segment. This ensures that the new snippet goes in the right pace on the page.

Answer (score 1):

There a a few ways to include ccs in html

Tis i use if you have it stored as a external file:

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" /></head>
```

If You want to put it stight i the html file:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
hr {color:sienna;}
p {margin-left:20px;}
body {background-image:url("images/back40.gif");}
</style>
</head>
```

Or if you wnat to modify a singel tag:

```
<p style="color:sienna;margin-left:20px">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

***Edit**

Any of thees examples shouldn't have any problem whit displaying.

Ref: [W3 Schools CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Comment: The problem is that I load the HTML form a webpage, so I can't change the HTML. I want to add code with jsoup and then load my own css.

Comment: I see, Your question was misleading sounded like you had control over the html. I edited the question to point others in the right way. I myself don't have any exp. whit jsoup