# How to add a new html tag with Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, html, dom, jsoup

I'm having some trouble adding a new tag to my Document. For example I have:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
Element table = doc.select("table").first();
```

Now If I want to add a `<LINK>`tag with attributes (href,type,rel) to my table element, and then return the total as a string, How would I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614352/add-custom-css-to-html-code-with-jsoup

Comment: ^^ I'm having problems with the adding the one to the other (too).

Comment: Now you must share what is the problem you are having? since the procedure for adding tags and attributes to an Element is given in the link I shared.

Comment: @djaqeel The link doesn't say anything about actually adding an tag, only about changing it's attributes. . .

Comment: table.append("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://example.com/your.css\" />");

Doesn't it help?

Answer (score 8):

Use something like this:

```
Jsoup.parse(new URL(""), 0).getElementById("test").appendElement("h1").attr("id", "header").text("Welcome");
```

And all ".append*" methods.

Comment: Hi dude, this is not working. I got below exception: `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:`.

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite some time but I also searched through for it a while so I will share my answer. This is for Jsoup 1.13.1

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
Element table = doc.select("table").first();

table.appendElement("link").attr("href","example.com/file.css").attr("rel","stylesheet").attr("type","text/css");
```