# what method in jsoup can return the modified html?

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, html-parsing, jsoup

When I **parse** the html file(stored in native) with **jsoup**. I have modified some elements in the html file,**so I want to save the modified html, and replace the old one?**

Do any body know **which method** in jsoup can do the job?
Thank you  so much!!!

Comment: Sample: https://gist.github.com/4139609 (The code is not exactly compilable, though, but the important part of the code are there). You can modify the code a bit to make it replace the old code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could write the contents of either

```
document.toString()
```

or

```
document.outerHtml()
```

to file, where `document` is got from

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://...").get();
// any document modifications...
```

like so:

```
BufferedWriter htmlWriter = 
     new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile), "UTF-8"));
htmlWriter.write(document.toString());
```

Comment: I am a beginner in programming.That's it !thaks!

Comment: like glen said in his answer, you should close() your used streams.

Answer (score 2):

Change your modified jSoup Element to HTML String:

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#html%28%29

```
String html = document.html();
```

Write to file:

```
Writer writer = new PrintWriter("/file.html", html);
writer.write(html);
writer.close();
```

More info here:
   [Add custom css to html code with jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614352/add-custom-css-to-html-code-with-jsoup)

Answer (score 2):

the declared answer that has 6 votes is correct all except for one part, it needs 1 more line of code.

Either "htmlWriter.close();" OR "htmlWriter.flush();" or both if you want. At the end of his code segment because I had the same issue and I used his version but he was missing this part (seen from the first comment on the post: gist.github.com/4139609.  So the finished code segment is:

```
BufferedWriter htmlWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile), "UTF-8"));
System.out.println("\n" + doc.outerHtml());
htmlWriter.write(doc.toString());
htmlWriter.flush();
htmlWriter.close();
```