# Modifying HTML using java

Tags: java, html, parsing, dom, jsoup

I am trying to read a HTML file and add link to some of the texts :

for example :
I want to add link to "Campaign0" text. :

```
<td><p style="overflow: hidden; text-indent: 0px; "><span style="font-family: SansSerif;">101</span></p></td> 
<td><p style="overflow: hidden; text-indent: 0px; "><span style="font-family: SansSerif;">Campaign0</span>
<td><p style="overflow: hidden; text-indent: 0px; "><span style="font-family: SansSerif;">unknown</span></p></td>
```

Link to be added:

```
<a href="Second.html">
```

I need a JAVA program that modify html to add hyperlink over "**Campaign0**" .

How i do this with Jsoup ?

I tried this with JSoup :

```
        File input = new File("D://First.html");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
        Element span = doc.select("span").first(); <-- this is only for first span tag :(
        span.wrap("<a href="Second.html"></a>");
```

Is this correct ?? It's not working :(

***In short*** : is there anything like-->

```
 if find <span>Campaign0</span> 
 then replace by <span><a href="">Campaign0</a></span>
```

using JSoup or any technology inside JAVA code??

Comment: text = text.replaceAll("<span style='font-family: SansSerif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: normal;'>Campaign0</span>","<a href='second.html'><span style='font-family: SansSerif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: normal;'>Campaign0</span></a>"); Did you try this?

Comment: Check this:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541460/what-method-in-jsoup-can-return-the-modified-html][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541460/what-method-in-jsoup-can-return-the-modified-html

Comment: span.text().replaceAll("Campaign0","<a href='second.html'>Campaign0</a>");span.text().replaceAll("<span style='font-family: SansSerif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: normal;'>Campaign0</span>","<a href='second.html'><span style='font-family: SansSerif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: normal;'>Campaign0</span></a>");


Not Working :( no changes appears.

Comment: Have you checked out [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)?

Comment: @Ascalonian well as you can see I am using Jsoup :P

Comment: @newProgramer - That's what I get for trying to answer without my coffee! Sorry about that haha

Comment: Can you alter your question to show the exact output you're looking for?

Comment: @Ascalonian little modification in question. please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems pretty much correct. To find the span elements with "Campaign0", "Campaign1", etc., you can use the JSoup selector "span:containsOwn(Campaign0)". See additional documentation for JSoup selectors at [jsoup.org](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

After finding the elements and wrapping them with the link, calling doc.html() should return the modified HTML code. Here's a working sample:

input.html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><p><span>101</span></p></td>
        <td><p><span>Campaign0</span></p></td>
        <td><p><span>unknown</span></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p><span>101</span></p></td>
        <td><p><span>Campaign1</span></p></td>
        <td><p><span>unknown</span></p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code:

```
    File input = new File("input.html");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
    Element span = doc.select("span:containsOwn(Campaign0)").first();
    span.wrap("<a href=\"First.html\"></a>");
    span = doc.select("span:containsOwn(Campaign1)").first();
    span.wrap("<a href=\"Second.html\"></a>");
    String html = doc.html();
    BufferedWriter htmlWriter =
            new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.html"), "UTF-8"));
    htmlWriter.write(html);
    htmlWriter.close();
```

output:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <table> 
   <tbody>
    <tr> 
     <td><p><span>101</span></p></td> 
     <td><p><a href="First.html"><span>Campaign0</span></a></p></td> 
     <td><p><span>unknown</span></p></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
     <td><p><span>101</span></p></td> 
     <td><p><a href="Second.html"><span>Campaign1</span></a></p></td> 
     <td><p><span>unknown</span></p></td> 
    </tr> 
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey thanks for reply but i think your will work only with first <span> encountered. In my case this is not the first <span> :(

Comment: Which span exaclty do you want to add the link to? The first one with content "Campaign0", or some other rule?

Comment: Actually there are many span like "Campaign0","Campaign1","Campaign2","Campaign3" .. etc all over the html file. Different will have different html file hyperlink.

Comment: So the problem is which span elements to select for modification. Can you expand your input example to contain the surrounding <table> element and another span that needs to be modified? Could the selection rule be something like "span element inside second td element of each tr element inside the table"?

Comment: Could the selection rule be something like "span element inside second td element of each tr element inside the table"? 
YES this is the case i want to apply for current html. but i may have different need for some other html i will generate. so my question is Can i replace **<span>Campaign0</span>** with **<span><a href="">Campaign0</a></span>** , not depending on where it is in whole html.

Comment: is there anything like-- if find **<span>Campaign0</span>** then  replace by **<span><a href="">Campaign0</a></span>** using JSoup or any technology inside JAVA code??

Comment: Finding <span>Campaign0</span> would be easy using selector like doc.select("span:containsOwn(Campaign0)"). You said the content of the span can be different, like "Campaign1" - do you know all the possible values the span can contain? If you have a list of "Campaign0", "Campaign1", ...,  you could iterate through the list and select each span using span:containsOwn(Campaign0) etc.

Comment: Yes I have the list of values on which i have to add link. So Element span = doc.select("span:containsOwn(Campaign0)"); with span.wrap("<a href=\"Second.html\"></a>") will work right ??. Thanks a ton :)